# Commutation with the exponential operator

Tags: operator-theory

Does the operator $e^{\frac{i}{\hbar }t\hat{H}}$ commute with $\hat{H}$?
I want to show that the expectation value of the Hamiltonian, in quantum mechanics, does not change with time, and I think that is correct to say that:

$$\left\langle \Psi \left( t\right) \right\vert \hat{H}\left\vert \Psi \left(
t\right) \right\rangle =\left\langle \Psi \left( 0\right) \right\vert \hat{U}%
^{\dagger }(t)\hat{H}\hat{U}(t)\left\vert \Psi \left( 0\right) \right\rangle
\\=\left\langle \Psi \left( 0\right) \right\vert e^{\frac{i}{\hbar }t\hat{H}}%
\hat{H}e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar }t\hat{H}}\left\vert \Psi \left( 0\right)
\right\rangle =\left\langle \Psi \left( 0\right) \right\vert \hat{H}e^{\frac{%
i}{\hbar }t\hat{H}}e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar }t\hat{H}}\left\vert \Psi \left(
0\right) \right\rangle \\=\left\langle \Psi \left( 0\right) \right\vert \hat{H}%
\left\vert \Psi \left( 0\right) \right\rangle 
$$
In the second line, I invoke the commutation of operators that I am talking about.

Comment: Yes. In the bounded case you can argue that it's a limit of polynomials in $H$ and these commute with $H$ and this passes to the limit. I'm not sure about the unbounded case but maybe you can do it by differentiating the commutator.

Comment: Are you assuming that $\hat{H}$ is self-adjoint and does not depend on time?

Comment: Yes. The Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$ is self-adjoint, and I am assuming that is time-independent. But also what if is time-dependent? What happens in that case?